# How to simplify the public void work(int hours) loop?

Tags: java

```
public static final int RETIREMENT_AGE = 65;
public Worker(String name, float hourlyIncome, int age,
         Worker coWorker) {
    this.name = name;
    this.hourlyIncome = hourlyIncome;
    this.age = age;
    this.coWorker = coWorker;
}

public void work(int hours) {
    for(int i = 1; i<=hours; i++) {
        earned += hourlyIncome;
        if(coWorker!=null && i%5==0)
            delegate(1); // from time to time
    }
}

public void work() {
    while(age++ < RETIREMENT_AGE)
    work(1600);
}

private void delegate(int hours) {
    coWorker.work(hours);
}
```

Asked to simplify the loop in public void work and I have no idea how to, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: First, make your indentation better, its currently really hard to read

Comment: It seems not too long or complex why do you want make it be simplyfy

Comment: Hint: what is the definition of `x + x + x + ... + x` added `y` times?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the same thing...

```
   public void work(int hours) {
        earned += hourlyIncome * hours;
        if(coWorker != null){
            delegate(hours / 5);
        }
   }
```

With the exception of the delegate method becoming more complex and the some internal state changing based on that.

Edit: And in that case, you could do something like

```
public void work(int hours) {
    earned += hourlyIncome * hours;
    if(coWorker != null){
        final int coworkerHours = hours / 5;
        for(int i = 0 ;  i < coworkerHours; i++){
           delegate(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only if `coWorker` did not override the `work()` method.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help puj. 

RealSkeptic: coWorker is actually an instance of Worker, not a subclass, so work couldn't be overridden by it...

Comment: @Jim McGee, the class doesn't guarantee that. You could pass an instance of a subclass of `Worker` to that constructor. If you are not going to allow it, declare the class `final` or the `work(...)` method final.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is incrementing age by one every time around the loop in the no-argument `work` method.  It may be possible, depending on what you do within the method, to reduce the number of calls to work(1600).

Specifically, if `work(2 * n);` produces the same result as `work(n); work(n);` you could just calculate the total number of hours before retirement and have a single call to work().

```
public void work() {
    if(age < RETIREMENT_AGE) {
        work((RETIREMENT_AGE - age) * 1600);
    }
}
```